# Getting value from toggle switch in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Super basic question, but I can't figure out why the following code won't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ckHr/3/

HTML

```
<label for="flip-1">Flip switch:</label>
<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select> 

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).delegate("#submit", "tap", function() {
    alert($("#flip-1").val());
});
```

Returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined (jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.js:2823)` when submit is pressed.

Comment: Changing `tap` to `click` makes it work for me. Is there a difference between the two in jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use **`vclick`** instead of **`tap`** or **`click`**. It is a jQuery Mobile event that bridges a mobile and desktop problems with tap/click not working on both platforms.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2ckHr/9/

```
$(document).delegate("#submit", "vclick", function() {
    alert($("#flip-1").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit').on("click", function() {
    alert($("#flip-1").val());
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you changed instead of only posting code, because it will be more likely to help the OP?